# Reduce audio volume without control

Tags: javascript, html, audio, volume

I am looking for a way to reduce the volume of my audio automatically using the code without the control.

I tried this code but the audio volume didn't change:

```
<audio id= "audio1" onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()">
<source src="Audio\Jaunty Gumption.mp3"  type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<script>
function setHalfVolume() {
 var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");  
 myAudio.volume = 0.5; //Changed this to 0.5 or 50% volume since the    function is called Set Half Volume ;)
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: no, I am just using a simple html and mp3 files, the sound works fie but I am trying to reduce it a little bit

Comment: you should post the JavaScript related to the `.volume`

Comment: sorry mate, unable to reproduce your error in firefox, http://jsfiddle.net/pf1w05te/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `volume` method with the range `0.0` (silent) to `1.0` (loudest).

Here's a useful code snippet you'll find in the MDN:

```
<audio id="demo" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
<div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Play the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pause the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1">Increase Volume</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1">Decrease Volume</button>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

You can also do something like this:

```
var sound = document.getElementById("myAudio");
sound.volume = 0.2;
```

Here's a link where you can get more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp